# There's "ghosts" and then there's...?

Tags: single-word-requests

Despite the tag, I'm actually looking for **two** words: you have ghosts, which are "otherworldly" in their nature with their intangibility (looking for an adjective), and then you have regular things from our world (also looking for an adjective). I know there are words for both in that context, but I just can't remember what those words are.

I'll try to specify more: lets say your ghost had a necklace that is part of their ghostly..."body". Just like the ghost itself, you can't physically touch that necklace. If you had to compare that necklace with a regular necklace, what would you call the ghost necklace and what would you call the regular necklace?

Comment: Supernatural and natural?

Comment: @KateBunting _not exactly_, but good guess. I'll try to specify more: lets say your ghost had a necklace that is part of their ghostly..."body". Just like the ghost itself, you can't physically touch that necklace. If you had to compare that necklace with a regular necklace, what would you call the ghost necklace and what would you call the regular necklace?

Comment: You could say the "material world", as opposed to the "spiritual world".  The thesaurus entry for "ghostly" might help, eg http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/ghostly?s=t - suggestions include "spectral", "unearthly" etc

Comment: There are *real* and *etherial*, and also *ephemeral*. These work from the real perspective, but don't really ascribe an intrinsic property to the ghostly stuff.

Comment: There's also _corporeal_, as in "corporeal beings", contrasting with _incorporeal_.

Comment: @noClue You said it already: *intangible* and *tangible* respectively.

Comment: @MrLister THANK YOU! Those were the words I've been looking for! Man... I'm not a native english speaker, but I heard of these words before, I just couldn't remember them. Thanks! Feel free to post an answer below, I'll accept it. (spectral is also good btw.)

Comment: @noClue OK. I'm not a native speaker either though...

Comment: @MrLister You're better than me, though, that's for sure. Tnx for the answer btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments indicate, there are various words describing the difference you're after.

- corporeal vs incorporeal
- material vs spiritual (from Max Williams)
- natural vs supernatural (from Kate Bunting)
- real vs ethereal or ephemeral (from Phil Sweet)
- tangible vs intangible (from Dan Bron)
- and spectral (from you), leaving the real-word counterpart as an exercise to the reader

(Making this a community wiki, because all the suggestions were at least as good as mine.)